# 30Mb limit uploading to Azure DataLake using DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient

Tags: c#, azure, azure-data-lake

I am receiving an error when using

```
_adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.Create(_adlsAccountName, destFilePath, stream, overwrite)
```

to upload files to a datalake.  The error comes up with files over 30Mb. It works fine with smaller files.

The error is:

> at
>   Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store.FileSystemOperations.d__16.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store.FileSystemOperationsExtensions.d__23.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store.FileSystemOperationsExtensions.Create(IFileSystemOperations
>   operations, String accountName, String directFilePath, Stream
>   streamContents, Nullable`1 overwrite, Nullable`1 syncFlag)    at
>   AzureDataFunctions.DataLakeController.CreateFileInDataLake(String
>   destFilePath, Stream stream, Boolean overwrite) in
>   F:\GitHub\ZutoDW\ADF_ProcessAllFiles\ADF_ProcessAllFiles\DataLakeController.cs:line
>   122

Has anybody else encountered this?  Or observed similar behaviour? I am getting around this by splitting my files into 30Mb pieces and uploading them.

However this is impractical in the long term because the original file is 380Mb, and potentially quite a bit larger.  I do not want to have 10-15 dissected files in my datalake in the long term.  I would like to upload as a single file.

I am able to upload the exact same file to the datalake through the portal interface.

Comment: I've hit the same issue several times. We worked round it by outputting to a temporary file path first. Then use the upload option. In C# use string tempOutput = Path.GetTempPath() + ouputFileName;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It answered [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/48e86ce8-79f8-4412-838f-8e2a60b5f387/notfound-error-on-call-to-data-lake-store-create?forum=AzureDataLake).

Currently there is a size limit of 30000000 bytes. You can work around by creating an initial file and then append, both with stream size less than the limit.

Comment: Thanks we tried both answers and they both work. We decided however using the built in upload function was simpler than our own function with append and create.

Answer (score 2):

Please have a try to use `DataLakeStoreUploader` to upload file or directory  to DataLake, more demo code please refer to [github sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-get-started-net-sdk.md). I test the demo and it works correctly for me. We can get the [Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store/1.0.2-preview) and [Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.StoreUploader](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.StoreUploader/1.0.0-preview) SDK from the nuget. The following is my detail steps:

1. Create a  C# console application
2. Add the following code

   ```
    var applicationId = "your application Id";
    var secretKey = "secret Key";
    var tenantId = "Your tenantId";
    var adlsAccountName = "adls account name";
    var creds = ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(tenantId, applicationId, secretKey).Result;
    var adlsFileSystemClient = new DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient(creds);
    var inputFilePath = @"c:\tom\ForDemoCode.zip";
    var targetStreamPath = "/mytempdir/ForDemoCode.zip";  //should be the '/foldername/' not the full path
    var parameters = new UploadParameters(inputFilePath, targetStreamPath, adlsAccountName, isOverwrite: true,maxSegmentLength: 268435456*2); // the default  maxSegmentLength is 256M, we can set by ourself.
    var frontend = new DataLakeStoreFrontEndAdapter(adlsAccountName, adlsFileSystemClient);
    var uploader = new DataLakeStoreUploader(parameters, frontend);
    uploader.Execute();
   ```
3. Debug the application .

   [image]
4. Check from the azure portal

[image]

SDK info please refer to the packages.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store" version="1.0.2-preview" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.StoreUploader" version="1.0.0-preview" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" version="3.13.8" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime" version="2.3.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure" version="3.3.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication" version="2.2.0-preview" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.2-beta1" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```